# Image link works only on one side of image

Tags: html, css

My problem is that i have two images which load another page on click. But the first button works on on clicking the left side of it. I ha eno idea why. This is html

```css
#gb1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 350px;
  left: -100px;
}

#gb2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 350px;
  right: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="gb1" align="center">
  <a href="_1"><img src="gb1.png" height="10%" width="20%"></a>
</div>
<div id="gb2" align="center">
  <a href="_2.html"><img src="gb2.png" height="10%" width="20%"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you ruled out the possibility that the `left` and `right` properties, declared respectively, could be overlaying each other? Troubleshoot this by experimenting with `z-index` values for both images.

Comment: Please add images - for example from lorempixel

Comment: The images are overlapped on each other.

Comment: The error lies in `<a href="_1">`

Comment: Combination of problems - broken link with _1 and also probable overlapping confusing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your div tag , change  as currently its just _1, change something like this:

```
<div id="gb1" align="center">
  <a href="_1.html"><img src="gb1.png" height="10%" width="20%"></a>
</div>
```